# File system for Pipe Device

Tags: filesystems, pipe

From Chapter 5 of the book **The design of Unix operating system** by Bach, an algorithm to create an (unnamed) pipe is given. It states that,

`assign an inode from pipe device (algorithm ialloc)`

A pipe device is just a file system designated for pipe device from which kernel can assign inodes and data blocks to the pipes.

I want to know more about this pipe device specific file system. Can anyone suggest where to look for it?

Comment: Ok, the book is from 1986, if I googled correctly. Are you interested in the implementation details in the context of 30+ year old book; or in details on how things work in practice on more-or-less current systems; or in how things work in the abstract based on (current or historical) standards and customs?

Comment: @ilkkachu I would like to know how things work in the abstract based on standards and customs...

Answer (score -2):

The sources for the file system in question are here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/uts/common/fs/fifofs/

also have a look at this man page:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man3c/fattach.3c.html

`fattach()` allows to mount a FIFO based object on top of a file.